# Creating a user in Meteor and in a 3rd party service via http at the same time

Tags: api, meteor, methods

I've got quite a complicated interaction that I'm just overwhelmed with.

My application allows users to register an account. When they register, I call a Meteor Method that also uses their registration details to register them an account on an external application using the API. (single sign on).

My problem is, the external API returns an ID which I need to associate with the user in my database.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's my code

Client side registration code:

```
Template.register.events({
'submit #signUpForm': function(e, t) {
e.preventDefault();

var signUpForm = $(e.currentTarget),
    forename = trimInput(signUpForm.find('#forename').val()),
    surname = trimInput(signUpForm.find('#surname').val()),
    email = trimInput(signUpForm.find('#signUpEmail').val().toLowerCase()),
    password = signUpForm.find('#signUpPassword').val(),
    passwordConfirm = signUpForm.find('#signUpPasswordConfirm').val();
    profile = {forename: forename, surname: surname};


if (isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(password) && isEmail(email) && areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)) {

  Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password, profile: profile}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.message === 'Email already exists. [403]') {
        console.log('We are sorry but this email is already used.');
      } else {
        console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Congrats new Meteorite, you\'re in!');
      Meteor.call('createUser', email, forename, surname); //registers user on external app using API
      Router.go('/');
    }
  });

}
return false;
},

});
```

and here's the method I'm using

```
Meteor.methods({
'createUser': function(email, forename, surname) {


  var endPoint = "/user"

  HTTP.call( verb, 'http://sandbox.wceaapi.org/v1.1'+ endPoint, {
    headers: {
      "Request-Time": timeStamp,
      "Api-Key": key,
      "Signature": hash
    },
    data: {
      "email": email,
      "name": forename,
      "surname": surname
    }
  }, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
      } else {
        console.log( response );
        var result = JSON.parse(response.content);

        var id = result.records.id;
        console.log(id); //this ID is what I want to then pass back to client and attach to the new user in the database.
      }
    });//end function error response
}// end createUser
});//end method
```

The ID variable that I'm retrieving from the API is what I want to then attach to the new user's account. I don't know how to do this.

**Bonus points** Right now, the user account is being registered on my site even if it fails on the remote server. How can I make it so the user account isn't registered on either if there is a problem? This is quite a complex interaction for a newbie like me so your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

**EDIT**

Following Michael's advice below - I've added a callback that if the external API registration fails, I log the user out then delete them from my database. This isn't working though. Also, the external API allows me to delete a user, and I've created a method to do so, but I just don't know how to call that method on the client side and then proceed with user registration based on whether it's successful or not - so I decided to do it in the order Michael suggested.

Here's the updated code (ignore the console.log they are for testing)

```
Meteor.methods({
'createWceaUser': function(email, forename, surname) {

  var endPoint = "/user";

  HTTP.call( verb, 'http://sandbox.wceaapi.org/v1.1'+ endPoint, {
    headers: {
      "Request-Time": timeStamp,
      "Api-Key": key,
      "Signature": hash
    },
    data: {
      "email": email,
      "name": forename,
      "surname": surname
    }
  }, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
        console.log(error);
        Meteor.logout();
        Meteor.users.remove({ _id: Meteor.userId() });
      } else {
        console.log( response );
        var result = JSON.parse(response.content);
        var id = result.records.id;
        console.log(id);
        Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $set: { 'profile.wceaId': id }});
      }
    });//end function error response
}// end createWceaUser
});//end method
```

The error I get is "Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Object # has no method 'logout'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the bonus points first. What you're looking for is analogous to a *two-phase commit.* Two different databases need to be in sync. Since you don't have control over one of them then you need to be careful about the order you call them in. For example if wceapi.org won't let you *delete* a user then you need to create a user there *after* you've created one in Meteor. Let's assume that's the case since that's the pattern you've posted.

So let's start with:

1. Create the user in Meteor.
2. Once the Meteor user has been successfully created, create the user in wceapi.org with the `HTTP.call`
3. If wceapi.org fails, **remove** the Meteor user. You can do this on the server in the failure condition of the callback with:

   ```
   Meteor.users.remove({ _id: Meteor.userId() });
   ```

Secondly, you don't need to update the wceapi.org id in your Meteor user document on the client, you can just do it directly on the server in the success condition of the callback with:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() },{ $set: { wceapiId: id }});
```

or

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId() },{ $set: { 'profile.wceapiId': id }});
```

if you want to store the wceapiID in the profile section of the user document. The advantage there is that it will automatically be published to the client. If you make it it's own root level key in the user document then you will have to publish it from the server and subscribe to it from the client. Since you're a newbie go with the profile subkey.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it. Your answer is totally clear and I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Michael, can I pick your brain again briefly... I've edited the method so that if the API registration fails, the user is logged out and the account is deleted, but it's resulting in an error. I'm posting the code etc above below the original question

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` will be undefined after the logout. Save the user id into a variable first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes total sense, can't believe I didn't think of that. I'm still getting an error about the logout though. It says "Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Object # has no method 'logout'"

Comment: Oh so sorry, logout is only available on the client. Try skipping that step. Not sure if Meteor will let you delete a user you just created from the creation callback.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1) webhooks- some api's offer to call you back if you register a webhook url for them, which you can easily do with your router in meteor.

2) hit them again after some time, or resolve a promise with a callback